# Magento 2.4 - Error encountered after installing new theme error: Requested path '' is wrong

Tags: magento2.2.4, custom-theme, magento-framework

I installed a third party theme and for some reason it broke my Magento server, Now I am unable to see the frontend and backend. I cannot access the admin panel to switch it back to the default luma theme. Please help me, what is this error?

Your kind help is highly appreciated. Please assist thanks.

Frontend:

Requested path '' is wrong.

```
#1 Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/static.php:13]
```

Comment: Has someone here already encountered this error before? can you help to share your solution?

Comment: in theme installation and configuration have you modify any file?

Comment: Try to check by change the theme from the database.
Run below query. and flush the cache.
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 2 WHERE path="design/theme/theme_id"